# Proper way to do a lisp program on lisp manipulaton

Tags: list, lisp

Just writing a simple program to learn how to manipulate list.  The external file has two column : bookname ISBN-no.  Sample:

```
+ How to Read the Bible: History, Prophecy, Literature--Why Modern Readers Need to Know the Difference and What It Means for Faith Today - ISBN-13: 978-0195383300
+ Who Wrote the Bible? - ISBN-13: 978-0060630355
```

The functions will allow user to select and generate another file sorted by ISBN-no or bookname.

I started to write it but then after one hour finding my approach is not very lisp.  The core logic is like a parser:

```
(defun proc-ls-str (ls)
  (let ((str+ "")
        (str- "")
        (first- t)
        (in+ t))
  (cond ((null ls) 
         (progn
           (format t "(never this) str+ is ~a str- is ~a~%" str+ str-)))          
        ((equal (car ls) '+)  
         (progn
           (format t "(only this) str+ is ~a " str+)
           (setf str+ "+")
           (setf first- t)))
        ((equal (car ls) '-)
           (setf first- nil)
           (setf in+ nil))
        (t (progn
             (proc-ls-str (cdr ls)))))))
```

It would work ultimately and in fact I wrote a similar program in Swift for handling comma-delimited-allowing-quote.  But it is not really learning Lisp.

Any suggestion about my approach?  Any sample I can read.  (Source code not books, got lots of them.)

Comment: "Any suggestion about my approach?"  You don't need to use **progn** with **cond** clauses; they already accept multiple forms.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be disappointed in some of the simplest ways to parse this type of content, but it's not particularly hard in Common Lisp.  First, let's put that file content in a string (we can read from the string through a stream later):

```
(defparameter *file-content*
  "+ How to Read the Bible: History, Prophecy, Literature--Why Modern Readers Need to Know the Difference and What It Means for Faith Today - ISBN-13: 978-0195383300
+ Who Wrote the Bible? - ISBN-13: 978-0060630355
")
```

Now let's define a **parse-file** function that reads lines from a stream and separates them into components by stripping off the prefix and splitting the remainder based on the occurrence of a separator string.  We can specify the prefix and separator, but I've provided default values based on the file content.

```
(defun parse-file (&optional
                     (in *standard-input*)
                   &key
                     (prefix "+ ")
                     (separator " - ISBN-13: "))
  (loop
     with prefixlen = (length prefix)
     with seplen = (length separator)
     for line = (read-line in nil nil)
     for split = (search separator line)
     until (null line)
     collect (cons (subseq line prefixlen split)
                   (subseq line (+ seplen split)))))
```

Now we can get the file content as a stream using **with-input-from-string**, and we can parse the stream:

```
CL-USER> (with-input-from-string (input *file-content*)
           (parse-file input))
(("How to Read the Bible: History, Prophecy, Literature--Why Modern Readers Need to Know the Difference and What It Means for Faith Today"
  . "978-0195383300")
 ("Who Wrote the Bible?" . "978-0060630355"))
```

Comment: Thanks for both the progn comment and the sample.  I got a few ah-ha moment (e.g. in reading the lisp program for ELIZA using associate list etc and the Ansi CL on network search).  Hence see whether any different way to attack the problem.  May be this type of programming is just loop-test-extract is more normal.  BTW, the use of loop is great.   Get one more skill to learn and think of.  It is not very Lispish.